# Using Horoscope API Objects In HTML

Tags: html, json, oop, api-design

I'm working on creating a website that uses a horoscope API to generate the horoscopes themselves. The API I'm using creates a JSON object with four elements: sunsign, meta, horoscope, and date. All I want to use is the horoscope itself: since the url for the api results already includes the date and sign, and the meta isn't needed, there's no point in making it more complicated.

The API is from this site: 
http://theastrologer-api.herokuapp.com/api/horoscope/taurus/today

What I'm having trouble with is referencing the horoscope of the object. I can't tell if I'm formatting the output improperly so the webpage won't display it, or if the reference itself is flawed. If anyone could help me with figuring that out and correcting it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Your Daily Horoscope</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" media="all" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="icon/x-icon" href="icon.jpg" />
</head>

<body>
    <img class = "banner" src="horoscopebanner.jpg" />
    <h2>What's your day going to be? Find out now!</h2>
    <h4>If this is your first visit, scroll on down to your horoscope. Select your sign at from the bottom radial buttons, 
so when you join us next time, your horoscope will be at the top of the list!</h4>
<div class = "horoscopes" id="aries">
    <img class="signs" src="aries.jpg" alt="Aries Sign" align="left" />
</div>
<div class = "horoscopes" id="taurus" >
    <img class="signs" src ="taurus.jpg" alt="Taurus Sign" align="left" />
</div>
/* Rest of the signs and their horoscopes here */

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://theastrologer-api.herokuapp.com/api/horoscope/taurus/today";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
function myFunction(response) {
    var object = JSON.parse(response);
    var out = "<p>";
    out += object.horoscope + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("taurus").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for any help given.

Comment: Just use a ready-made API like https://horoscopesapi.com